# php date issue when converting using strtotime, but how to do this properly?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Using the following code to try and get 'Y-m-d', and should return 2016-05-10, but it is instead returning 2016-10-05.

```
// m-d-Y (Month-Day-Year)
$test_date = '05-10-2016';

// Convert to Y-m-d
$convert_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($test_date));


echo $convert_date;
```

How do I get 'Y-m-d' returned?  Not trying to use `explode('-', $test_date)`.  Is this possible to do using proper time functions?

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of strtotime. you used `-` to separate the components, so strtotime decides it's dd-mm-yyyy. if you'd used `/`, then it'd be treated as `mm/dd/yyyy`. Do **NOT** use strtotime to parse ambiguous inputs. in fact, if you KNOW the format of the date string in advance, don't even bother trying to use strtotime. use `date_create_from_format()` and get a 100% reliable parsing.

Comment: Wow, thanks, didn't know this.

Comment: [PHP Documentation of date formats for strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `DateTime` object for this:

```
$test_date = '05-10-2016';
$DateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $test_date, new DateTimeZone('utc'));
var_dump($DateTime);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
object(DateTime)[8]
  public 'date' => string '2016-05-10 15:08:53.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 2
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

So

```
echo $DateTime->format('Y-m-d'); //2016-05-10
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` assume European formatted dates if they are seperated by `-` and USA date format if they are seperated by `/`

> Note: [from the manual strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So you can just `str_replace` the `-` for `/`

```
// m-d-Y (Month-Day-Year)
$test_date = '05-10-2016';
$test_date = str_replace('-', '/', $test_date);

// Convert to Y-m-d
$convert_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($test_date));

echo $convert_date;
```

Or better still use the [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Note: Be aware of dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats; if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed. If the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. To avoid potential errors, you should YYYY-MM-DD dates or date_create_from_format() when possible.

**Source:** [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)

You have to convert '**-**' by '**/**'.

```
<?php// m-d-Y (Month-Day-Year)
$test_date = str_replace('-', '/', '05-10-2016');

// Convert to Y-m-d
$convert_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($test_date));

echo $convert_date; // 2016-05-10
```